# Azure - Publishing from VStudio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

Using VStudio 2010 wizard to set up basic 'Hello World' asp.net web role, works under emulator but when importing publish file from azure management portal get error 
'publishsettings does not contain valid publish settings for Windows Azure'.

Have set up web site, storage and cloud service in Azure latest management portal (preview version) so unclear what problem is.

Comment: Just to be clear, the file you're trying to import into Visual Studio is the .publishsettings file obtained from the Windows Azure portal (e.g. http://manage.windowsazure.com).  Correct?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Windows Azure Websites (Preview) and using Visual Studio Publish wizard for your application you would need to download the publish file from your website located as shows below:

[image]

After that you can just use this .publishsettings file in VS Publish wizard and there not even a single click needed and your website will be published.

Please see my latest blog: [Deploying Windows Azure Website using Visual Studio Web Publish wizard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/26/deploying-windows-azure-website-using-visual-studio-web-publish-wizard.aspx)

Comment: I see how this works in VS12, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get the Web Publish Wizard to show up in VS10.  All I see is the old `Publish Web` tool.

Comment: I think if you install the sdk or smth you get a "publish to Azure" option. Im only here because it rejected my file even then :(

Comment: I also got same issue in VS 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. 
Seems like the publishsettings files related to specific sites/services/apps are always rejected.
The solution seems to be to get a publishsettings file for your *entire Azure account* instead, and after that you're able to access your sites/services/apps or create new ones and publish to them.
This is performed using the following steps:

. Right click the project in VS10 and open 'Publish...' (the Azure
   publish settings) 
 . Go to the Summary tab. Here you are able to download a publish settings file related to your Azure *account*. This file is named something like 'three month free evaluation period 1-1-2013-credentials.publishsettings' rather than the publish settings file for a particular site, which would be named somethiung like 'mysite.azurewebsites.net.publishsettings'. Import that file - it will work!
 3. Now go to the settings tab. Here you can select a cloud service (select existing or you can create a new one) and assign some settings.

[image: step 3]

. When the configuration is complete and you've clicked the Next button, VS10 will start deploying your project to the selected service. This is displayed in the 'Windows Azure Activity Log' output window in VS10.

[image]